# How to set a .htaccess custom rewrite?

Tags: php, html, apache, mod-rewrite

I am currently trying to achive this:

```
pageurl/profile/username
```

Instead of

```
pageurl/profile/?username=username
```

How i can do this in the right way? I have googled for a long time to find a right way, only nothing works for me, when I'm trying to edit this the way I want to use this.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is it save to say you have your vhost setup to use `.htaccess` and that `mod_rewrite` is installed? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming username is the username rather than the string "username" - I've removed the `pageurl` part as it seems like boilerplate.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ /profile/?username=$1 [L]
```

This is for inside an .htaccess file at the **document root** (not within a sub-folder) - the rule is very slightly different if you were to add it to a `<VirtualHost>` in httpd-vhosts.conf for example.

---

Since you've actually got a directory called `/profile` however, you're likely to encounter a terminal loop with `/profile` redirecting to `/profile` redirecting to `/profile` ad infinitum.

To avoid this you'll need **not file** and **not directory** conditionals:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ /profile/?username=$1 [L]
```

This will prevent URLs like `/profile/index.php` from redirecting to `/profiles/?username=index.php` as the request must be **neither** a file nor a directory.

Comment: So i addd that into my htaccess, only its not working i want my url like this profile/alex  alex is the username.

Comment: Try it without the *pageurl*s ... I wasn't 100% certain whether you'd left it in as boilerplate or not. Oh, and your .htaccess will need to be in the document root - not any subfolder.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the structure of the maps.

Comment: Yeah your `href`s will be of the form `<a href="/profile/alex">Alex's Profile</a>` or similar... and from the screenshot, it looks as though your docroot is the `/public` directory, so your .htaccess is in the right place.

Comment: ... looking at it though, you may have an issue with the fact that there's an actual directory called `profile` as `profile/index.php` will route to `profile/index.php?username=index.php` which will loop to `profile/index.php?username=index.php` and so on ... forever, I'll update the answer to take this into account.